# Error processing package libsofia-sip-ua-glib3

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Due to errors because of full disk space maybe some packages were not installed while upgrading from Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10. Adding or removing any program leaves me with an error :

```
dpkg: error processing package libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

I am new to Ubuntu and learning...Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What exactly did you do to provoke this error message? Which command(s) did you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have resolved your disk space problem,this will handle the error:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsofia-sip-ua-glib3
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Just edit your post, it should be "--reinstall"

Comment: @aakash-choubey: Thanks for pointing out my typo

Comment: Please "accept" my answer, by clicking on the checkmark. This will help my reputation grow, so that eventually, I can Rule The World!